# Wait for event when fragments fully initialized in FragmentPagerAdapter to setup them with data

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, tabview

I have an activity with collapsing `AppBarLayout`. In `onCreate()` method I am sending request to server to get some data. And depending what data I get - I need to dynamically in runtime choose what view to show to the user: 1. MyFragment1; or 2. `TabLayout`/`ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which has two fragments in it. And I need to set some data to that fragments. But the issue is in next: I already have data and set it to fragments in my adapter, but fragment method `onCreate` is not yet called, and my layout is not initialized. That's how I get crash on populating data into layout view. So, how can I make somehow - fragment created and initialized it's fields first and only then setup it with data? Thanks.

```
    private MenuFragment1 menu1Fragment1;
    private MenuFragment3 menu1Fragment3;
    private TabMenuAdapter adapter;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        menu1Fragment1 = new MenuFragment1();
        menu1Fragment3 = new MenuFragment3();

        adapter = new TabMenuAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(menu1Fragment1, "Menu 1");
        adapter.addFragment(menu1Fragment3, "Menu 2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

public onDataLoaded(String data)
{
//at this point, fragment is created, but it's View fields are NULL!!
menu1Fragment1.data = data;
}


@Layout(id = R.layout.content_shop_final)
public class ShopFinalTermsFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private static final String SANS_SERIF_FAMILY_NAME = "sans-serif";
    private static final String SANS_SERIF_MEDIUM_FAMILY_NAME = "sans-serif-medium";

    private InfoModel InfoModel;
    private RateModel RateModel;

    @BindView(R.id.shop_final_nested_scroll_view)
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    @BindView(R.id.shop_final_pending_txt)
    TextView pendingDurationTxt;

    @BindView(R.id.shop_final_rate_cond_rv)
    RecyclerView rateCondRv;

    @BindView(R.id.shop_final_description_txt)
    TextView descriptionTxt;

    @Inject
    ToolsManager toolsManager;

    RateConditionsAdapter adapter;


    private String getParams;

    public static ShopFinalTermsFragment newInstance(String getParams, InfoModel shopInfoModel, RateModel RateModel) {
        ShopFinalTermsFragment fragment = new ShopFinalTermsFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(SHOP_GET_PARAMS, shopGetParams);
        args.putSerializable(INFO_MODEL_KEY, shopInfoModel);
        args.putSerializable(MODEL_KEY, userCashbackRateModel);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.GetParams = getArguments().getString(SHOP_GET_PARAMS);
            this.InfoModel = (InfoModel) getArguments().getSerializable(INFO_MODEL_KEY);
            this.RateModel = (RateModel) getArguments().getSerializable(RATE_MODEL_KEY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupInOnCreateView() {
        nestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            conditionsTxt.setTypeface(Typeface.create(SANS_SERIF_FAMILY_NAME, Typeface.BOLD));
        } else {
            conditionsTxt.setTypeface(Typeface.create(SANS_SERIF_MEDIUM_FAMILY_NAME, Typeface.NORMAL));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void inject() {
        ShopsComponent shopsComponent = DaggerShopsComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getApplicationComponent())
                .build();
        shopsComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public void setupWithData(InfoModel InfoModel, RateModel RateModel) {
//THIS METHOD IS COLLED FROM ACTIVITY'S onDataLoaded(InfoModel InfoModel, RateModel RateModel) method
        setupShopInformation(shopInfoModel);
        setCashBackRateModel(userCashbackRateModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post crash logs

Comment: Could you show us the `Fragment` class ?

Comment: added fragment class to description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the dependency in a wrong way. It's not the activity that should call `setupWithData` on a fragment but it should be a fragment getting data from the activity (or other storage) instead. This way you will break this dependency on the fragment lifecycle which ends up being uninitialized.

Get the data from the server, store it where you need to, and update the UI from your activity. At this point you either show `MyFragment1` or your `TabLayout/ViewPager`. If it's a `TabLayout` or a `ViewPager`, all you do is creating fragments and adding the to the layout or a corresponding pager adapter. That's it. You don't set the data at this point.

Now when your inner fragments populate in the pager adapter, they will go through `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onResume` lifecycle methods. `onResume` is a good place to load the data. You either access it directly from the fragment, or get it from your outbound activity - depends on what makes more sense for you. If you need an activity reference, you can access it via `getActivity()` method in the fragment.

So in the fragment's `onResume` you will have something like:

```
setupShopInformation((YourActivity) getActivity()).getShopInfoModel());
setCashBackRateModel((YourActivity) getActivity()).getUserCashbackRateModel());
```

Although it would be even better to have it stored in some state class. But that will be a separate question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I understand now. But the reason why I need to set data from activity - is that I don't want to recreate visual representation of fragment, because if I do so - then my collapsing appbarlayout stop respond to scrolling events, because it handles referance to previous fragment. That's why I only need to refresh data. Can I set it from activity directly?

Comment: These two things are unrelated. How many fragment instances do you have? If it's one fragment and only the UI is changing, then you can safely set data from activity because `onCreate` was called on the first UI load. So if you get the crash, then most likely you replace the fragment itself, i.e. its a new instance. In this case you shouldn't set data from activity because the code will be complex - it will involve scheduling a UI task and waiting for the UI initialization.

Comment: Your app bar layout scrolling shouldn't depend on the fragment at all. It listens to layout scroll events which is always there. If the container remains the same, then the scroll should work normally. You can always maintain the scroll position too, depending on the container you use.

Comment: I have two fragments, and they don't have a lot of data. Appbar should work normally, but under debug, I found that it keeps referance to the old fragment. And if I try move my finger on Collapsing part of the layout after recreation of fragments - it is not scrolling, but when I move my finger on new fragment's layout - it reinitializing itself and now is scrollable. It is 100% reproducable. I event made small test project with it. And in case I don't recreate fragments, but only populate them with new data - everythig works fine.

Comment: hmm, I haven't seen anything like that yet.. I don't think I can resolve that issue in chat, sorry.. Dealing with the UI and app bar scrolling has always been a bit hectic and required thorough debugging and playing with the layout. Do you have a control over Appbar instance creation? You should be able to reset the fragment reference yourself.

Comment: If you are interested - I can upload this one test activity with working test project to github and give you link?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't have that much time for debugging.. Try to separate loading data from rendering as much as possible, figure out if it's a purely rendering problem or data loading problem. If still unable to resolve on your own, please narrow down as much as possible and post as a separate question on SO, including your layout files and details about how you initialize your Appbar and where it doesn't work. I hope this helps.. Good luck!